# Alternative to Reflux for client and server (individual sessions)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

I have been using [RefluxJS](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs) for a web application, and it works very well. The problem is on the server side (node/express). It uses singeltons, and I have not found any way to use it without mixing data between sessions. When one user store some data in a store, that data is still there when another user (different session) make requests to the backend later. Even if i removed the data at the end of the request, there could be mixups when processing multiple requests.

So, is there a good alternative to Reflux that works well on both client and server? I am looking for the simplification that exists in Reflux, and at the same time being decoupled, not building the flux structure around and into the whole application (like Fluxible does).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check out http://alt.js.org/ ? Or http://acdlite.github.io/flummox ? Or https://github.com/gaearon/redux ?

Comment: Reflux also has an issue on making it more isomorphism-friendly, but the progress seems slow: https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs/issues/144

Answer (score 0):

I tackled the same problem using Backbone for data management, and I ended up with something like this:

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({})
var exported
if ( isNode ) {
  module.exports.init = function(session) {
    session.collection = new Collection()
    exported = session.collection
  }
} else {
  exported = new Collection()
}
module.exports.collection = exported
```

And then call the `init(session)` from your NodeJs, f.ex:

```
var data = require('data')

[...]

index: function(req, res, next) {
  // attach backbone collection to the session
  data.init(req.session)
  // now you can use data.collection as normal
}
```

On the client you can just require and use it as normal. It works surprisingly well for us so far, but I’m open for other suggestions as well.

We use Backbone only for data management and to implement a flux-like architecture using backbone events.

Facebook Relay looks promising too, but no release date is set: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/02/20/introducing-relay-and-graphql.html